# How to change HTML element without ID using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list with 250 countries in a HTML dropdown(for the sake of space I've only included 5 below):

```
<select name="postalCountry" class="valid">
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AX">Aland Islands</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
    <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
```

Unfortunately I cannot edit the HTML element themselves, so I was wondering if there is a way to hide all of them except for Alaska (value=AK) using Javascript?

I currently have the following:

```
var country = document.querySelectorAll('select[name="postalCountry"] option');
var e;

for (e = 0; e < country.length; e++){
country[e].style.display = 'none';
}

country[2].style.display = 'initial';
```

But that gets a bit messy since I would have to go through a lot of countries to find out the index number of a country at the end of the list.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated !

Comment: That's the correct way to do it, unless you want to get fancy with `map`, which on a list that small won't make much of a difference in performance anyway.

Comment: so read the text or value and see if it matches....

Comment: You can not hide `<option>` in some browsers notably IE. You have to remove or disable

Comment: You can use jQuery.

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca There's no array where you could call `.map()` on. And why a method to translate every element into another one if the purpose is to only change one attribute of the elements?

Comment: @Andreas I think I've seen `map` used for side effects. `country` is the array, in this case.

Comment: So the jQuery code will look like this.
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('option[value != "AF"]').css('display', 'none');
});

Comment: @Andreas, sorry, confused `forEach` with `map`. Can't correct the original comment

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca `country` is not an array. It's an array-like `NodeList`.

Comment: @Andreas see previous comment. `forEach` works with `NodeList`s (at least in my browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can use the "value" of each option like follows

```js
var country = document.querySelectorAll('select[name="postalCountry"] option');
for (var e = 0; e < country.length; e++){     
  if(country[e].value == "AK"){
   country[e].style.display = 'initial';      
    document.getElementById("country_select").value = country[e].value;
  } else {
   country[e].style.display = 'none';
  } 
}
```

```html
<select name="postalCountry" id="country_select" class="valid">
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AX">Aland Islands</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
    <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only going to style them it's better to just use CSS:

```css
select[name="postalCountry"] option
{
  display: none;
}

select[name="postalCountry"] option[value="AK"] 
{
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<select name="postalCountry" class="valid">
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AX">Aland Islands</option>
    <option value="AK" selected>Alaska</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
    <option value="DZ">Algeria</option
```

Edit: added `selected` attribute so "Alaska" is selected by default initially.

Comment: And your answer shows the value as `Afghanistan` :) so needs one more thing.

Comment: I Was going to add this answer XD

Comment: Yep I added selected attr so Alaska is selected :)

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to make Alaska the first element of the select element, and set the select's value to "AK":

```
var sel = document.querySelector('select[name="postalCountry"]');
    optAK = document.querySelector('option[value="AK"]');

sel.prepend(optAK);
sel.value = 'AK';
```

In CSS, hide all but the first option:

```
select[name="postalCountry"] option:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

That will overcome a bug in Chrome which shows the first option even if it's hidden.

**Snippet:**

```js
var sel = document.querySelector('select[name="postalCountry"]');
    optAK = document.querySelector('option[value="AK"]');

sel.prepend(optAK);
sel.value = 'AK';
```

```css
select[name="postalCountry"] option:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select name="postalCountry" class="valid">
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AX">Aland Islands</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
    <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before we start: **the aceppted answer is right and works well**.

Here's an alternative approach showing the use of ES2015 [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) (`...`) to iterate through a `NodeList` as an `Array`. This way we can use `find` method to target the right `<option>` without the use of formal loops and conditions.

Remeber that it only works in [browsers that supports the spread operator](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-spread_(...)_operator) (anything but IE). Also, note that it's a kind of syntax sugar which can be considered better or worst based on personal preferences but being [a little slower](https://jsperf.com/spreap-operator-vs-traditional-iteration/1) than the traditional iterational approach, so use with sense.

```js
let options = [...document.querySelectorAll('#country_select option')]
options.forEach(e => e.style.display = 'none')

let selected = options.find(e => e.value === 'AK')
selected.style.display = 'initial'
selected.selected = true
```

```html
<select id="country_select">
  <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="AX">Aland Islands</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AL">Albania</option>
  <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
</select>
```